# TypeError: equals() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, typeerror

In my program I essentially want to return the result of a method that tests for equality between two students (i.e if the number of classes both have taken is equal)

I created a class called Student. I then created two functions and defined their attributes. I'm essentially trying to compare two objects within the student class and one method needs to check for equality between the two.

```
class Student:


    def __init__(self, name, age, classesTaken):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.classesTaken = classesTaken

    def equals (student):
        is_equals = student.name == self.name and student.age == self.age and 
        student.classesTaken == self.classesTaken
        return is_equals


mike = Student("Mike", 21, 25)
john = Student("John", 19, 22)

#problem starts here
print (mike.equals(john))
```

I keep getting the error:

> input Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 18, in
>
> print (mike.equals(john))                                                                                                                                                                                               TypeError: equals() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: A method of a call gets called with the `instance` implicitly. Do `def equals (self, student)` instead of `def equals (student)`

Comment: You missed to add the mandatory `self` arguments.

Answer (score 3):

add `self` to your `equals function` parameter

```
def equals (self,student):
```

Answer (score 3):

In python, instance methods take `self` as the first argument to refer to the instance their are called on:

```
def equals(self, student):
    # ...
```

that being said, you might consider overriding the  [dunder method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunder-magic-methods-python/) `__eq__`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    # ...
```

which will allow you to test equality more pythonically via `==`:

```
mike == john
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call a class method in an instance of this class, python implicitly passes a reference to the instance as a **first method argument**, that’s why it tells you that "equals() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

example:

```
class A:
  def method(argument):
    print(argument)

B = A()
B.method(new_argument) # it will raise the the same TypeError

# Because python will convert the call of class method like so:
A.method(B, argument)

# So the solution is to call it with the keyword 'self':
B.argument(self, new_argument)
```